# What's "Contemporary" Linguistics? What exactly is contemporary?

Tags: history-of-linguistics

[Academic linguistics commenced pretty recently](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/6908), compared to other sciences.

1. So what does "Contemporary" in "Contemporary Linguistics" mean?
2. What exactly is signified, if a book contains "Contemporary" in its title? Examples : University  Chicago Press printed four books for its series [Studies in Contemporary Linguistics](https://press.uchicago.edu/ucp/books/series/SCL.html) from Dec 1990 to Aug. 1994 "complete and closed to new submissions."

- Donald Brenneis. [*The Matrix Of Language: **Contemporary** Linguistic Anthropology*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0813323207).
- Andrea Ender et al. [*Methods in **Contemporary** Linguistics* (Trends in Linguistics: Studies and Monographs)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3110284669)
- William O'Grady. [***Contemporary** Linguistic Analysis*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321476662).
- John Archibald, Mark Aronoff, et al. [***Contemporary** Linguistics: An Introduction* (2017 7 edn)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1319039774)

Comment: This is an expression used by publishers to convey the impression of being "cutting edge, most up to data information". It helps to distinguish actually-current approaches from e.g. the 2500 year old model of Panini.

Comment: As the guys on the Wiktionary discussion pages say, _contemporary linguistics_ is "SoP": "Sum of parts". The science of linguistics at the time of writing. There's no special meaning.

Comment: _Contemporary_ in a title indicates 'contemporary with this publication'. In other words, look at the copyright date. That's the semantics. The pragmatics is that it's cool, current, popular, elegant, and with-it. Next year, of course, things will be different.

Comment: We should also take into consideration production lags, where some years may pass between the final version and its actual appearance.

Comment: @jlawler Your “cool, current, popular, elegant, and with-it” for *contemporary* is exactly what people mean to imply whenever they use *modern* in things like *modern analysis* or *modern grammars* — or for that matter in *modern text editors* or *modern programming languages* besides. It’s mostly used as a marketeering check-off item like you'd find in Buzz-Word Bingo™ games. Notice that Fowler’s ***Modern** English Usage* dates from 1926. :)

Comment: So it doesn't mean the science of several people talking *at the same time*?